# How to add SPM dependency in PodSpec file?

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods, swift-package-manager, podspec

We have some libraries that support only SPM. But we need to add those libraries in our podspec file. How can we do that?

Tried to add spm dependency in podspec file by using s.spm_dependency .
[image]

Comment: There is no way to do so, there is no `spm_dependency` in https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podspec.html

Comment: Thanks @Larme, I agree. Some one raised PR to add spm_dependency in pods but that PR is yet to merge